# Enter onkeyup not working in jsf2

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, authentication, icefaces, onkeyup

I'm migrating an application from icefaces 1.8 to icefaces 3.2. It's a complex application and i'm having problems with the login page in JSF 2.

in the page we had something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onEnter(ev)
     {  if(ev==13)
        { 
            document.getElementById('login:linkLogin').onclick();
        } 
     }
</script>
. 
.
.
<body onkeyup="onEnter(event.keyCode);">
.
.
.
<ice:commandLink id="linkLogin" action="#{loginBean.auth}" onclick=";encriptPass('#{login.rsaKeyMod}','#{login.rsaPubKey}');">
.
.
.
```

This works on jsf 1.2 + icefaces 1.8 withou problems.
But in jsf 2.1 + icefaces 3.2 I modified the code this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onEnter(ev)
         {  if(ev==13)
            { 
                document.getElementById('login:linkLogin').onclick();
            } 
         }
    </script>
    . 
    .
    .
 <h:body onkeyup="onEnter(event.keyCode);">
    .
    .
    .
    <ice:commandLink id="linkLogin" action="#{loginBean.auth}" onclick=";encriptPass('#{login.rsaKeyMod}','#{login.rsaPubKey}');">
    .
    .
    .
```

This code won't work this way. If I press enter, the form just resets and the bean.auth method is not even called.

What am I missing here. Does JS behaves differently in jsf2?.

**EDIT:**
I've found a solution in this thread:
[Submit action by the enter key](http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/4273.page)
The last post has the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting enter while the form is in focus, it will submit the form (if you have a submit button) and go to the URL you have defined in the form action attribute.  You need to prevent this default behaviour by listening to the submit event of the form and running the preventDefault function.

```
$('#someform').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I don't have a submit button in the form. The authentication it's done through linkLogin action method LoginBean.auth(ActionEvent e).